# How can I convert a Char(16) column into a Date Datatype column?

Tags: sql

I imported a CSV file (2 million records) into a derby database but always struggled to import the column with this content: "2002-09-06 00:00" as a TIMESTAMP datatype. So I changed the database column to Char(16) instead of TIMESTAMP and was able to import the file without an error.

Now I would like to convert the Char(16) column with 2 million records into a DATE datatype column or copy and convert it into a new column with DATE Datatype. Or whatever other solution you can come up with!

I was thinking of something like this

```
CONVERT(DATE, 101)
```

but I have no idea how to connect it with the already existing column.. I really suck at SQL.

Help would be appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: If all your date/time values have this format, the simplest approach is `ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c DATE`. This will cause SQL Server to rewrite the table, applying implicit conversion, and as long as all values are of the `yyyy-MM-dd` form, this is safe. (It will not work correctly for all locales if your target type is `DATETIME`, because this is not one of the [safe formats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166771/97345), and you would need a dance with `CONVERT` then.)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is pretty good about converting date/times.  So you can just use:

```
convert(datetime, '2002-09-06 00:00')
```

or better yet:

```
try_convert(datetime, col)
```

I recommend loading the data into a *staging* table.  Then transforming it in the database to the structure that you want.  That way, you can investigate any conversion issues (or other transformation issues) because you have the loaded data.

Comment: This is a good answer.  I do a lot of bulk loading to temp tables and then run conversions when selecting data into a new, final table.  Having everything as VARcAHR/NVARCHAR instead of individual types makes the ETL process a bit smoother.